# Using YUI 3 Event with custom events in browser plugin

Tags: javascript, yui3, browser-plugin, firebreath

I made a plugin with [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/), with a custom event, and I would like to register a callback with YUI Event.

```
Y.on( "mycustomevent", callback, pluginNode );
```

Does not register my callback, whereas

```
pluginNode.addEventListener( "mycustomevent", callback, false );
```

does (on Firefox, not on IE).

How can I use YUI to register my event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Adding my event to Y.Node.DOM_EVENTS, it works:

```
Y.mix( Y.Node.DOM_EVENTS, {
    mycustomevent: 1
} );
```